# IntentService - Wakelock release issue

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentservice, wakelock

I have an alarm application. 
**Flow looks like this :**

> WakefulBroadcastReceiver(Acquires wakelock)  --->> Intent service -->> startActivity

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, TriggeredActivity.class);
        activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(activityIntent);
```

Basically WakefulBroadcaseReceiver starts an intent service using startWakefulService(). Inside intent service's onHandleIntent(), only work I am doing is further starting a new activity using  startActivity(). That new activity is where I am using mediaPlayer in a loop, which sounds the alarm. That activity has a dismiss button, which waits for user click to stop the media player & activity finishes.
Now the problem I am facing is that after calling startactivity() inside intent service, I can not wait for TriggeredActivity to finish(no equivalent to startActivityForResult in Service) and then complete wakeful intent. Related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284849/android-service-worker-thread-launches-activity-and-waits-a-response)

> startActivity(activityIntent);
>       WakefulBCastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent); /* can't do here */

**So I am not explicitly releasing wakelock here.**

My question is will the wakelock be released automatically(link-to-death), when the process that is holding it is killed.
If yes, then in my particular scenario, I need not call WakefulBCastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent().

Comment: your process is not killed, you need to `release()` your `WakeLock`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use *completeWakefulIntent*.

You need to put your *TriggeredActivity* intent into EXTRAs.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent intentService = new Intent(context, NotificationsIntentService.class);
    // Inserting data inside the Intent
    intentService.putExtra(NotificationsIntentService.EXTRA_NOTIF, new Intent(context, TriggeredActivity.class));
    startWakefulService(context, intentService);
}
```

**NotificationsIntentService.class**

```
public class NotificationsIntentService extends IntentService {

     private static final String TAG = "DebugNotifIntent";

     public static final String EXTRA_NOTIF = "extra_notif";

     public NotificationsIntentService(){
         super(NotificationsIntentService.class.getSimpleName());
     }

     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: ");
          Intent extraIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_NOTIF);
          extraIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(extraIntent);

          NotificationWakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
     }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution for my problem. I am now using a Messenger for message based cross process communication between intent service & triggered activity.
I am passing a handler - alarmServiceHandler, from intent service to activity through a messenger.

```
Handler alarmServiceHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.arg1 == 1) {
            completedTriggeredActivity = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Inside onHandleIntent(), I am passing handler through Messenger object in intent's extra data.

```
    Messenger alarmServiceMessenger = new Messenger(alarmServiceHandler);
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, TriggeredActivity.class);
    activityIntent.putExtra("AlarmServiceMessenger", alarmServiceMessenger);
    activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(activityIntent);


    while(!completedTriggeredActivity){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    WakefulBCastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
```

In TriggeredActivity, I am retrieving messenger in Dismiss button's OnClickListener, just before calling finish() on the activity. And sending back a message to AlarmService with arg = 1, implying end of processing in triggered activity.

```
buttonDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Messenger alarmServiceMessenger = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("AlarmServiceMessenger");
                Message alarmServiceMessage = Message.obtain();
                alarmServiceMessage.arg1 = 1;
                try {
                    alarmServiceMessenger.send(alarmServiceMessage);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finish();

            }
```

After starting triggered activity, I am putting AlarmService in sleep mode till boolean variable completedTriggeredActivity  has not been set to true in handleMessage(). Once true, it means triggered activity has finished & now I can proceed with releasing wake lock.

I would be glad to receive comments about my approach & any suggestions towards a better solution to my problem, than the one I have deviced.